# All methods of including webpage returning blank or error in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to include the contents of a webpage, it works fine on localhost, but when I upload the file to a server it no longer works

I've tried `file_get_contents()`, `cURL`, `fopen`, they all work fine on my PC, but fails online.

Is there a variable in PHP.ini that my host will have set to stop me getting the contents of other pages?

```
<?php


$url = 'http://www.example.com';

echo stream_get_contents( fopen($url, 'r') );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);     

echo $output;


echo file_get_contents( $url );
?>
```

Errors:

> Warning: fopen(http://www.example.com): failed to open stream: Network
>   is unreachable in /srv/disk12/1999559/www/techmex.co.nf/test.php on
>   line 6
>
> Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /srv/disk12/1999559/www/techmex.co.nf/test.php on
>   line 6
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com): failed to open
>   stream: Network is unreachable in
>   /srv/disk12/1999559/www/techmex.co.nf/test.php on line 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most webservers disable this feature by default but if you have access to change your php.ini you should set "allow_url_fopen = On".

You can also try:

```
<?php
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
?>
```